# Safari shows blank page on ASP.NET timeout, RedirectToAction() redirection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timeout, mobile-safari

The project is developed using `.NET Framework 4.5`. When the app makes an API request and it times out, the `RedirectToAction("Fail")` doesn't work as expected, resulting in a blank page.
This issue is specifically observed in the Safari browser; both web browsers and Android Chrome work correctly, allowing for successful page redirection. It's worth noting that this problem occurs consistently only when the entire API request duration is relatively short.

The Front-end simplified, back-end uses redirection, but Safari seems unrelated. Suspect Safari malfunction after timeout, specifically with `RedirectToAction()`. The prior code runs fine.